# Don't understand why these two queries give different results

Tags: sql-server, aggregation

I have three tables (for sake of argument) individual, email and attribute. individual_Ref the foreign key that links individual to email and attribute.

It isn't necessary for a given individual to be represented on the attribute table as they may never have had an attribute added and they can appear more than once if they have more than one attributes.

I want get a list of individual references and a count of a particular attribute for them. But need to search by email address as it is allowed for individuals to share email addresses (don't get me started)...

My first stab was

```
select e.individual_ref, count(a.attr_Code_ref)
from email e left join attribute a on e.individual_Ref = a.individual_ref
where e.email_Address = 'example.email@adomain.net'
and a.attr_code_Ref = 4119 
group by e.individual_ref
```

using a left join to ensure I get an individual ref from email if one exists and to ensure I get a result if there is an individual ref in email but not in attribute. Or so I thought since this returns no rows but...

```
select e.individual_ref, 
(select count(a.attr_Code_ref) from attribute a where a.attr_code_Ref = 4119 and a.individual_ref = e.individual_ref)
from email e
where e.email_Address = 'example.email@adomain.net'
group by e.individual_REf
```

returns one row with an individual_Ref and a count of 0

I'm not suggesting SQL is broken more that my understanding is... so I guess "what's my confusion?" is the question.

Comment: +1 for getting folks to consider the effect of a WHERE clause in context with the JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting a subquery to a `LEFT JOIN`, the correlated `WHERE` conditions in the subquery go to the `ON` clause of the join, not to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT  e.individual_ref, count(a.attr_Code_ref)
FROM    email e
LEFT JOIN
        attribute a
ON      a.individual_ref = e.individual_Ref
        AND a.attr_code_Ref = 4119 
WHERE   e.email_Address = 'example.email@adomain.net'
GROUP BY
        e.individual_ref
```

Comment: I guess it's obvious I'm self-taught and that a little knowledge is a dangerous thing :-) Thanks for your answer - things are a bit clearer now...

Answer (score 3):

the following part causes the join to alter:

```
from email e left join attribute a on e.individual_Ref = a.individual_ref 
where e.email_Address = 'example.email@adomain.net' 
and a.attr_code_Ref = 4119
```

By placing a where clause on the a.attr_code you have turned the left join into an inner join e.g. where no attribute record exists, it returns null, which fails the where clause. (since a.attr_code_ref can't be 4119, there was no record.)

You would need to allow `a.attr_code_ref = 4199 or a.attr_code_ref is null`

Comment: Definately shorter, but I'm wondering (havnt checked) whether doing that keeps it SARGable or not. Function applied to the field being tested tends to break it.

Comment: `= null` is never true; try `is null`

Comment: That returns 0 rows as well... I guess that maybe it is still being converted to an inner and the where clauses are still returning no rows in attributes

Comment: oddly this made me think of doing:

select e.individual_ref, count(a.attr_Code_ref )
from email e left join attribute a on a.individual_ref = e.individual_ref
where e.email_Address = 'darrenmcallister@btopenworld.com'
group by e.individual_Ref
having a.attr_code_Ref = 4119

but that complains that attr_code_ref isn't in an aggregate function which I thought it was...

Comment: <doh>I've just googled having and it doesn't work like that</doh>

Answer (score 1):

Change the first one in:

```
select e.individual_ref, count(a.attr_Code_ref)
from email e left join attribute a on e.individual_Ref = a.individual_ref
where e.email_Address = 'example.email@adomain.net'
and (a.attr_code_Ref = 4119 or a.individual_ref is null)
group by e.individual_ref
```

and you get the same results

Answer (score 0):

In the first query, you are joining the two tables and looking for any rows that correspond to both your conditions - there are none.

In the second query, you are getting the rows from the first table the correspond to the email condition (there is one), and the number of rows that correspond to your second condition from the other table, there are 0 of those.